# How do I disable the message and style of an item when validation is valid?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I'm using VUE 3 Composition API and want to do additional validation in front-end.
Tailwind library - "TW Elements" is plugged into my project, which already has ready-made forms with validation.
After studying the documentation of "TW Elements" I didn't understand how to disable the message and style of an element when it passes validation.

Sample code with validation from the [TW Elements](https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/validation/#advanced-example) documentation that I'm trying to use:

HTML:

```
<form data-te-validation-init>
  <div
    class="relative mb-3"
    data-te-input-wrapper-init
    data-te-validate="input"
    data-te-validation-ruleset="isRequired">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="peer block min-h-[auto] w-full rounded border-0 bg-transparent px-3 py-[0.32rem] leading-[1.6] outline-none transition-all duration-200 ease-linear focus:placeholder:opacity-100 data-[te-input-state-active]:placeholder:opacity-100 motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-neutral-200 dark:placeholder:text-neutral-200 [&:not([data-te-input-placeholder-active])]:placeholder:opacity-0"
      id="exampleFormAdvancedInput1"
      placeholder="Example label" />
    <label
      for="exampleFormAdvancedInput1"
      class="pointer-events-none absolute left-3 top-0 mb-0 max-w-[90%] origin-[0_0] truncate pt-[0.37rem] leading-[1.6] text-neutral-500 transition-all duration-200 ease-out peer-focus:-translate-y-[0.9rem] peer-focus:scale-[0.8] peer-focus:text-primary peer-data-[te-input-state-active]:-translate-y-[0.9rem] peer-data-[te-input-state-active]:scale-[0.8] motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-neutral-200 dark:peer-focus:text-primary"
      >Example label
    </label>
  </div>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="inline-block rounded bg-primary px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-white shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca] transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-600 hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:bg-primary-600 focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-700 active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] dark:shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.5)] dark:hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]"
    data-te-submit-btn-ref>
    Validate
  </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
import {
  Validation,
  Input,
  initTE,
} from "tw-elements";
initTE({ Validation, Input });
```

[image]

**How do I disable the message and style of an item when validation is valid ?**

Comment: You can check the API docs (https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/validation/#docsTabsAPI) where it says you can update class based on kind of validation you need.

Comment: In your case it's `basicInputInvalid` class key where you can modify the class `!border-[#dc4c64] focus:!border-[#dc4c64] focus:!shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_#dc4c64]`

Comment: @MJN I don't understand where to change this. I tried to change the styles through CSS. I also changed the basicInputValid to " " in the validation.js file at the path \node_modules\tw-elements\dist\src\js\forms\validation. That didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom data attributes on `form` element to customize for your needs. Adding `data-te-class-XXX` where `XXX` is list of attributes key given in [API Docs here](https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/validation/#docsTabsAPI%20classes) . Example shared below where `data-te-class-notch-trailing-valid="..."` is the one you are looking for.

Here is the stackblitz Demo: [View Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wmcr6y?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTwElements.vue) where the valid border is changed to grey from green

[image]

```html
<form data-te-validation-init data-te-class-notch-leading-valid="border-[#d4d4d4] dark:border-[#d4d4d4] group-data-[te-input-focused]:shadow-[-1px_0_0_#d4d4d4,_0_1px_0_0_#d4d4d4,_0_-1px_0_0_#d4d4d4] group-data-[te-input-focused]:border-[#d4d4d4]" data-te-class-notch-middle-valid="!border-[#d4d4d4] dark:border-[#d4d4d4] group-data-[te-input-focused]:shadow-[0_1px_0_0_#d4d4d4] group-data-[te-input-focused]:border-[#d4d4d4]"
  data-te-class-notch-trailing-valid="border-[#d4d4d4] dark:border-[#d4d4d4] group-data-[te-input-focused]:shadow-[1px_0_0_#d4d4d4,_0_-1px_0_0_#d4d4d4,_0_1px_0_0_#d4d4d4] group-data-[te-input-focused]:border-[#d4d4d4]">
  <div class="relative mb-3" data-te-input-wrapper-init data-te-validate="input" data-te-validation-ruleset="isRequired">
    <input type="text" class="
          peer
          block
          min-h-[auto]
          w-full
          rounded
          border-0
          bg-transparent
          px-3
          py-[0.32rem]
          leading-[1.6]
          outline-none
          transition-all
          duration-200
          ease-linear
          focus:placeholder:opacity-100
          data-[te-input-state-active]:placeholder:opacity-100
          motion-reduce:transition-none
          dark:text-neutral-200 dark:placeholder:text-neutral-200
          [&:not([data-te-input-placeholder-active])]:placeholder:opacity-0
        " id="exampleFormAdvancedInput1" placeholder="Example label" />
    <label for="exampleFormAdvancedInput1" class="
          pointer-events-none
          absolute
          left-3
          top-0
          mb-0
          max-w-[90%]
          origin-[0_0]
          truncate
          pt-[0.37rem]
          leading-[1.6]
          text-neutral-500
          transition-all
          duration-200
          ease-out
          peer-focus:-translate-y-[0.9rem]
          peer-focus:scale-[0.8]
          peer-focus:text-primary
          peer-data-[te-input-state-active]:-translate-y-[0.9rem]
          peer-data-[te-input-state-active]:scale-[0.8]
          motion-reduce:transition-none
          dark:text-neutral-200 dark:peer-focus:text-primary
        ">Example label
      </label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="
        inline-block
        rounded
        bg-primary
        px-6
        pb-2
        pt-2.5
        text-xs
        font-medium
        uppercase
        leading-normal
        text-white
        shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca]
        transition
        duration-150
        ease-in-out
        hover:bg-primary-600
        hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)]
        focus:bg-primary-600
        focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)]
        focus:outline-none
        focus:ring-0
        active:bg-primary-700
        active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)]
        dark:shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.5)]
        dark:hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]
        dark:focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]
        dark:active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]
      " data-te-submit-btn-ref>
      Validate
    </button>
</form>
```